# client to server delay estimation - over UDP

Tags: c++, sockets

My homework is to write function  that get client to server delay estimation.
I need to send from the client 50 request of "what is the time?" and than to receive 50 responses from the server ( by getTickCount()) - and than to calculate average.
  the problem is that for some reason the second recv function crashed and i dont know why.
this is part of my code ( from my client):

```
    WSAData wsaData; 
if (NO_ERROR != WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData))
{
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at WSAStartup()\n";
}
SOCKET connSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);
if (INVALID_SOCKET == connSocket)
{
    cout<<"Time Client: Error at socket(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
    WSACleanup();
    return;
}

sockaddr_in server;
sockaddr serverr;
int server_len = sizeof(server);
server.sin_family = AF_INET; 
server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
server.sin_port = htons(TIME_PORT);

int bytesSent = 0;
int bytesRecv = 0;
string sendBuff;
char recvBuff[255];

        for (i=0 ; i<50;++i) 
    {   
        bytesSent = sendto(connSocket,sendBuff.c_str() , (int)strlen(sendBuff.c_str()), 0, (const sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server));
        if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesSent)
        {
            cout<<"Time Client: Error at sendto(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
            closesocket(connSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
    }
    for (i=0 ; i<50;++i) 
    {
         bytesRecv = recv(connSocket, recvBuff, 255, 0);
        if (SOCKET_ERROR == bytesRecv)
        {
            cout<<"Time Client: Error at recv(): "<<WSAGetLastError()<<endl;
            closesocket(connSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return;
        }
```

Comment: Can we assume the `100` in the comments is a typo?

Comment: We are missing a lot of context. It would be best if you could supply a short, complete program. See http://sscce.org/. Failing that, what do you mean "crashed"? Is the connection TCP or UDP? What values does `bytesSent` and `bytesRecv` take on after the resp. system calls? How is `recvBuff` declared?

Comment: shouldn't you be using `recvfrom()`?? This is UDP right?

Comment: *Aside*: `strlen(sendBuff.c_str())` is silly. Prefer `sendBuff.size()`.

Comment: yes, this is UDP! the program just totally stuck after I select this function (if im running RTT calculation that is using same function but after each request it ask for response -no problem. the only difference is the continuous requests ).

Comment: You have the WSAGetLastError function called, what does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried switching to recvfrom? Since you are using sendto, its mirror function should make more sense.

Also, if you send your 50 requests before processing a single receive, your delay will not be any good. Your average should be calculated on multiple single send/receive pairs

Comment: basically my teacher gave us a simple example of client and server on UDP so I follow his code and all my other functions works great with recv . Anyway,I tried to use rcvform but Im getting same problem.
No I see I have also exception - First-chance exception at 0x757b6aff in comex3.exe: 0x40010005: Control-C. 
what does it mean??

Answer (score -1):

define two integers variables (start, end)
add this code after handling error in the for loop of messages were sent from server

```
            recvBuff[bytesRecv] = '\0'; //for handling null terminated to the answer

            if (i == 0)
            {
                start = atoi(recvBuff);
            }
            if(i == 50){
            end = atoi(recvBuff);
            }


        cout << endl << "Time Client: Delay Estimation:       " << (end - start) / 50<< " ms " << endl;
```